# Mathematics, combinatorics. What is the maximum number of variations?

Tags: math, combinatorics

There's this line.

`X1_X2_X3_X4_X5_X6`

It is known that each variable X* can take values from 0 to 100. The sum of all X* variables is always equal to 100. How many possible string variants can be created?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers.  Note the comment *it gets quite messy* !

Answer (score 0):

Suppose F(n,s) is the number of strings with n variables, and the variables sum to s, where each variable is between 0 and 100, and suppose s<=100. You want F(6,100).

Clearly

```
F(1,s) = 1
```

If the first variable is t, then it can be followed by strings of n-1 variables that sum to s-t. Thus

```
F(n,s) = Sum{ 0<=t<=s | F(n-1, s-t) }
```

So its easy to write a wee function to compute the answer.